# Can Amazon Pinpoint Monetization events be created via the REST API?

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I'm investigating Amazon Pinpoint as an SMS campaign engine which we would integrate via the REST APIs.

Having reviewed the documentation about Monetization events, they are only discussed in the context of iOS/Android SDKs or the JavaScript SDK.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/defining-a-monetization-event-sdk.html

The REST API documentation does not specifically mention Monetization events.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-events.html#rest-api-events-attributes-eventsrequest-table

Is it possible to use the REST API to create a monetization event? If possible, I'm assuming it is a particular value of EventType which I need to use for a monetisation event but this is not documented anywhere.

Thanks!

Michael